# Filter returned data from Ajax + Redirect with return data

Tags: php, ajax

I have a validation that, when successful creates a session variable:

```
if( password_verify($password, $artist_password) ) { // if this is true
            // create $_SESSION artist name
            $_SESSION['artist_name'] = $artist_name;
            return $artist_name;
        } else {
            echo "Incorrect Password";
        }
```

This validation is initiated by an Ajax request.

If there are errors with the validation, I echo a message.  This echoed message is received by the Ajax success method via the data argument.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../includes/login_validation.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: inputs,
    success: function(data){ 
        $("span#error_msg").html(data);
    }, 
    // returns 'Incorrect Password'
```

My problem is in defining the return response from the PHP file.

For example, when there's an error, the PHP script echoes a message and in turn this response is received and processed through the Ajax success method and placed into a html placeholder.

However, if the SESSION variable is assigned I want to return that data and include it in a redirect.

My question is, how can I discern between an echoed response as the return value and a returned value containing other data (e.g $_SESSION['artist_name']).

And if successful, how can I include it in my redirect so that the redirected page will have access to the session variable.

```
window.location.href="artistWorkshop.php"; // plus session variable
```

Comment: Why not make a `$_SESSION['incorrect']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about doing a little JSON formatting:

```
if( password_verify($password, $artist_password) ) { // if this is true
    // create $_SESSION artist name
    $_SESSION['artist_name'] = $artist_name;
    echo '{"status":"success","result":"'.$artist_name.'"}';
} else {
    echo '{"status":"error","result":"Incorrect Password"}';
}
```

Next, handle the output in JS:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../includes/login_validation.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: inputs,
    success: function(data){ 
        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
        if (obj.status == 'success') {
            // redirect
            window.location.href="artistWorkshop.php?artist="+obj.result;
        }
        if (obj.status == 'error') {
            // throe error
            $("span#error_msg").html(obj.result);
        }
    },
});
```

You could handle multiple formats this way. Problem was is the JS was interpreting any output as a success, because the AJAX call itself was successful. Now, you have a message to determine the actual result of the request. In your code, to determine an actual failure of the ajax request, your would need to include a `error` node:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../includes/login_validation.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: inputs,
    success: function(data){ 
        $("span#error_msg").html(data);
    },
    error: function(data){
        // handle the error
    },
```

If you go that route, check this out:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks man! I haven't learned about JSON yet but that seems like a really succinct way of doing it.  I appreciate your help!